# Ubuntu Xenial not mounting nfs version 4.1

Tags: 14.04, nfs

Our Ubuntu clients do not use NFS version 4.1 mounting from a server running Ubuntu trusty. The NFS version is 4.0.

It is possible to force version 4.1 by providing the "vers=4.1" mount option. Fedora 23 clients on the other hand mount using 4.1 per default.

Is there a specific reason for this behavior in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the version in the options.

i.e.  `mount -t nfs4 -o minorversion=1 server:/path /mountpath`

Tells it to use NFS v4 with a minor version of 1, so 4.1.